# Action Script 3. How to access button from Movie Clip in Flash?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

I have **MyMovieClip** named **mClip**. Inside mClip are 2 buttons named: **btn1 btn2**

[image: mc]

I need access these buttons in my Action Script code. I have declared It:

```
var mClip:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip();
var btn1:MyButton1 = new MyButton1();
var btn2:MyButton2 = new MyButton2();
```

I have tried in 2 ways, but both unsuccessfully:

**1.**

```
mClip.btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, popUp1);
mClip.btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, popUp2);

function popUp1(event:MouseEvent):void {
   trace("test 1");
}
function popUp2(event:MouseEvent):void {
   trace("test 2");
}
```

**2.**

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, popUp1); //removed mClip
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, popUp2); //removed mClip

function popUp1(event:MouseEvent):void {
   trace("test 1");
}
function popUp2(event:MouseEvent):void {
   trace("test 2");
}
```

I don't get any errors, just nothing happens after buttons is clicked. Could you help me, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is likely going on.  Though I have to make the following assumptions:

1. You are using flash pro
2. In flash pro, you've created a movie clip, placed it on the main timeline, and given it the instance name of **mClip**
3. On the **mClip** timeline, you've created two buttons and given them the instance names of **btn1** and **btn2**.
4. All your code is on the main timeline.

When you do the following:

```
var mClip:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip();
var btn1:MyButton1 = new MyButton1();
var btn2:MyButton2 = new MyButton2();
```

You are actually telling flash to take those names (mClip, btn1,btn2) and assign **NEW** objects to them (the old ones still exists, but the vars refer to the new objects you've just created - so your adding click events to objects that aren't on screen).

When you add a movie clip to the timeline and give it an instance name, behind the scenes it's effectively done the same as that code.   Remove those three lines, and your code from your first try will work. (assuming all my assumptions above are correct, please advise if not)

Answer (score 0):

The first try would be correct if the class is marked as `dynamic`. But as this is not your case, you should either use the variable directly:

```
btn1.addEventListener(..
```

**IF** this is used exactly in the same class that you define them (and add them in the mClip). What actually happens is that you work with the variable, rather than the instance name. You might have problem because you are not working where you define those buttons.

If that still doesn't work, you are probably clicking on something above that child.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your diagram, but the buttons should have colored (not empty) fields (although the alpha can be anything, including 'zero') -- so that you're actually clicking on something. And, if the 'buttons' are just MovieClips coded as buttons, the labels should be static text and non-selectable.

We're assuming that your code is timeline code, NOT part of coded classes.